# Spring boot deployment issue on jboss

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly

After deploying spring boot project on jboss ,every things work great except my schdule task.i have annotated my main class with @enablescheduling and @component on my schedule method class and @scheduled on my method.but after running successfuly without error on jboss ,my schedule task does not fire.i really need a solution.
Tnx every body
Below is my config class and my schedule classes:

```
@SpringBootApplicatio
@Enablescheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class);              

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}

@component
Public class test{
@scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
Public void print(){
//do sth
}

}
```

Comment: could you provide your schedule class configuration? also, if you can, share the app configuration (I mean Spring setup)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich check below please

Comment: ok, but it's better to move the configuration to the past. also please add the cron expression you're using in the '@Scheduled' annotation

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich what do u mean by past?

Comment: What do u mean by past?

Comment: to the post. sorry, I'm from my mobile phone, going from work

Comment: Cron or fixed delay both should do scheduled task not much diffrence ,main problem is about not running at all

Comment: I mean are you sure the expression is valid?

Comment: Yes im sure . I think @scheduled is not never seen during application boot

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich i edited the post

Comment: great, I will take a look when I'm home

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich tnx buddy

Comment: configuration seems to be ok, are you sure the component with the method to be schedule gets created?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich yes but in log i can see that no task scheduler or taak executor regiatered for processing

Comment: Every thing is ok i dont what is happening . I dont want to use xml config

Comment: got it. actually, we have a similar setup in our project. let me try it myself in my test project

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich looking forward to see ur solution tnx buddy

Comment: I made it work. try to use initialDelay with 10000 ms. it sounds kinda strange but please try and let me know if it works for you. also ensure you log in the method to schedule not with logger only but with simple `System.out.println` as well

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich also yours doesnt work without initial delay?

Comment: yes, maybe it is a bug. so does it work for you?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich yes bro.. i dont know how say tnq to you..i test in a sample project and worked but i have to test it at office the day after tomorrow on main project. Hope works in there. By the way im really happy and thats because of you. If it worked i will let u in and please post it as answer here to be voted.tnx again man

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich just one other question.your method never started after your fixedDelay time or didnt start immediately after server start up?because initail delay is used to after specific time start the schedule task. But in my case method never start.please clarify on this case?

Comment: At first it didn't worked. Then I added the attribute to the annotation and it worked. Now I tried to remove it and it worked. Strange o_0. Also check it you really need the `configure` method in the configuration class

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich i also removed configure method but no change.so there is no fixed solution?

Comment: I mean does it work when you remove the `configure` method and the `initialDelay` attribute?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich no diffrence . After removing configure method and without initial delay no success .how about u?do u have configure method and initial delay?

Comment: Well, actually, I'm extending the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class not the `SpringBootServletInitializer`. There is no such method. Now it works for me both with delay and not. But firstly it didn't work without

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich may i see ur main class?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich well my project is originally spring boot so i have to use springservletinializer but your project is a normal spring project with java config

Comment: sure, here is [my servlet setup](https://github.com/dmitrysenkovich/SpringAdvancedTraining/blob/mine/src/main/java/com/epam/spring/core/Application.java) and [web config](https://github.com/dmitrysenkovich/SpringAdvancedTraining/blob/mine/src/main/java/com/epam/spring/core/web/WebConfig.java). please, do not follow any style there as it is a test project that was originally based on work of another person so in whole it sucks:)

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplicatio
@Enablescheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class);              

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}

@component
Public class test{
@scheduled(fixeddelay.....)
Public void print(){
//do sth
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we've found an issue. Setting `initialDelay` to 10000 ms resolved the problem in our case. Don't know an explanation but still: it works.