# schedule task not working after deploying spring boot project in jboss, every thing works well except schedule tasks

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, jboss

schedule task not working after deploying spring boot project in jboss, every thing works well except schedule tasks

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception           
SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}
}

//this is schedule task class in diffrent package

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void reportCurrentTime() {
    log.info("The time is now {}", dateTest.format(new Date()));

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot depolyment issue on jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195407/spring-boot-depolyment-issue-on-jboss)

Comment: yes but if u know a solution please provide